# Average for each row in QuerySet

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to write a query that will return something like:

```
{idBlock: average_score, idBlock: average_score...}
```

or with values:

```
{1: 3.12, 2: 4.18...}
```

My model looks like this:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    idBlock = models.ForeignKey(Block)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
```

There will be thousands of block IDs probably, each one with several dozen scores, possibly thousands of scores. I have tried various queries from various sources, and this one is the closest to the solution that I need:

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(average_score=Avg('score')).values('idBlock','score')
```

which returns this:

```
{'idBlock': 6L, 'score': 6L}, {'idBlock': 6L, 'score': 9L}, {'idBlock': 7L, 'score': 5L}, {'idBlock': 7L, 'score': 8L}, {'idBlock': 8L, 'score': 6L}
```

The above query is not calculating the average...so my query is wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `Block`, not `MyModel`, that you should be annotating. Try:

```
Block.objects.annotate(average_score=Avg('mymodel__score'))
             .values('id','average_score')
```

Comment: It works, thank you. I guess I was reading this https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#generating-aggregates-for-each-item-in-a-queryset wrong.

Comment: You're welcome. See the section on [following relationships backwards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards) for the relevant example (averaging book ratings for each author).